# Extend the proof of the fact that the set $C(G)$ of continuous functions is dense in $L^2(G)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $G$ be a compact group. Show that the set $C(G)$ of continuous functions is dense in $L^2(G)$

Can anyone extend the following proof?

Proof. Arguing by contradiction, suppose that $C(G)$ is not dense.

1. Then there exists a nonzero $L^2$ function $h$ such that $\int_{G}fhdx=0$ for all $f\in C(G)$
2. By a passage to the limit, $\int_{G}fhdx=0$ whenever $f$ is the characteristic function of a compact set that is the countable intersection of open sets, then whenever $f$ is the characteristic function of an open set, and finally whenever f is the characteristic function of any Borel set.
3. Applying this conclusion successively when the Borel set is the set where $Re(h)>0$, the set where $Re(h)<0$, the set where Im(h)>0, the set where Im(h)<0, we coclude that $h$ is 0 almost everywhere, contradiction.

In (1) How do we guarantee the existence of such $h$? And why do we do this? I suppose to know the notion of density.

In (2) Which variable do we take limit with respect to? And why do we deal with the countable intersection of open sets?

Thanks!

Comment: Ad (1). Note that $L^2(G)$ is a Hilbert space and choose $h\in C(G)^\perp$.  Ad (2). Choose functions $0\le h_j\le 1$ that are one on $K$ and zero outside $U_j$.

Comment: Ad(2).  What are $K$ and $U_j$? Could you write the functions more explicitly? Thanks

Comment: $K$ is of course the compact set and the $U_j$ are the open sets whose intersection is $K$.

Comment: Under pretty general circumstances, every bounded Borel function is the a.e. pointwise limit of a uniformly bounded sequence of continuous functions (this follows from Lusin's theorem) . That will quickly give the result.